# spring batch AsynchJob Launcher ,Error in setting job repo

Tags: spring, asynchronous, spring-batch

Hi below is my configuration for creating asynchlob launcher

```
<bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="&amp;jobRepository" />
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor" />
</bean> 

 <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />

<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean" />
```

i'm getting below error

```
Error creating bean with name 'batchJobLauncher': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher com.batch.launcher.BatchJobLauncher.asyncJobLauncher; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncher' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/BatchConfig.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean' to required type 'org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository' for property 'jobRepository'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean] to required type [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository] for property 'jobRepository': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
.....
caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean' to required type 'org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository' for property 'jobRepository'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean] to required type [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository] for property 'jobRepository': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:512) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:506) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1523) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean] to required type [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository] for property 'jobRepository': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:287) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:461) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
... 60 more
```

i tried without & also.

error like this

```
13:58:59,346 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobBuilders' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory]: Factory method 'jobBuilders' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$99e29281 cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
```

Comment: Please note that tag [tag:batch-file] is `Windows`-related; so I adapted the tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example made from http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-hello-world-example/ and tested on wildfly 9.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    ">
    <bean id="report" class="Report" scope="prototype" />
    <bean id="jobRepository"
       class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>
    <batch:job id="helloWorldJob">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="cvsItemReader" writer="xmlItemWriter"
                                     commit-interval="10">
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
    <bean id="jobLauncher"
              class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
        <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="cvsItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">

        <property name="resource" value="classpath:report.csv" />

        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                        <property name="names" value="id,sales,qty,staffName,date" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="fieldSetMapper">

                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                        <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="report" />
                    </bean>

                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="xmlItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
        <property name="resource" value="file:/home/username/report.xml" />
        <property name="marshaller" ref="reportMarshaller" />
        <property name="rootTagName" value="report" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="reportMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
                <value>Report</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
              class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />
</beans>
```

Report.java:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "record")
public class Report {

    private int id;
    private String sales;
    private int qty;
    private String staffName;
    private String date;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "sales")
    public String getSales() {
        return sales;
    }

    public void setSales(String sales) {
        this.sales = sales;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "qty")
    public int getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(int qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "staffName")
    public String getStaffName() {
        return staffName;
    }

    public void setStaffName(String staffName) {
        this.staffName = staffName;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Report [id=" + id + ", sales=" + sales 
                    + ", qty=" + qty + ", staffName=" + staffName + "]";
    }

}
```

To run use a servlet with the following code:

```
     ApplicationContext context = 
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("job.xml");

JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
Job job = (Job) context.getBean("helloWorldJob");

try {

    org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it seems from application context i'm getting the launcher properly. It seems auto wiring is what causing that error. i removed autowiring on launcher its working.